# Fate of orphaned commits resulting from a rebase

Tags: git

Consider the (common) scenario of using the rebase command explained [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing). As described in that reference, rebase leads to the creation of *new* commits corresponding to those in the original feature branch.

I wonder what happens to the commits on the original feature branch. Are they automatically removed during the rebase operation, or will they stay around until a garbage collection operation is performed?

Note. I know it is not too difficult to run an experiment to get the answer to the above question. I do not have a handy repository ready and am trying to save some time here by relying on the knowledge of others!

Comment: The commits will, as you mention, be around for a while and will be available using `git reflog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tim Biegeleisen said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780818/fate-of-orphaned-commits-resulting-from-a-rebase#comment130281777_73780818), they stick around for a while, because `git reflog` hangs on to their hash IDs.  Other things (e.g., `ORIG_HEAD` or other branch or tag names) may also keep the rebased commits reachable.

Once the reflog entries and any other way of *finding* the commits are all gone, `git gc` *may* eventually erase them.  In your own local repository, various Git operations run `git gc --auto`, which checks to see whether Git thinks it's a good idea to do a `git gc` now.  If not, `git gc --auto` quietly exits without doing anything.  Otherwise, `git gc --auto` does an automatic, background garbage-collection pass.

Some Git repositories (specifically those created with `--bare`) normally have reflogs *disabled*.  In this case, the commits abandoned by `git rebase` can go away sooner:

- By default, `git gc` protects *any* "loose" object for a minimum of 14 days from its creation.
- By default, a reflog entry sticks around for at least 30 days, or 90 days, depending on whether the hash ID named *by* the reflog entry is "reachable" from the *tip commit* named by the reference whose log this reflog entry lives in.

So in a normal (non-bare) repository, commits live on for at least 30 days, and even in a bare repository, commits generally live on for at least 14 days.  But all of these are tunable.  This also doesn't cover the dance that occurs when an object (commit or other object) becomes *packed*, which is more complicated but doesn't *shorten* the lifetime here.

Some hosting sites—GitHub in particular act this way—*never* expire a commit, so as long as you know its hash ID, you can find it there.

Comment: "never expire a commit" So if you've leaked sensitive information into your code and you remove the offending file from all commits with `filter-repo`, you haven't really solved anything at all?

Comment: @matt: correct: you have to get hold of GitHub support and have them go in manually and toss it.